# For what purpose does "read" exit 1 when EOF is encountered?

Tags: shell, read

The bash man page says the following about the `read` builtin:

> The exit  status  is  zero, unless  end-of-file  is  encountered

This recently bit me because I had the `-e` option set and was using the following code:

```
read -rd '' json <<EOF
{
    "foo":"bar"
}
EOF
```

I just don't understand why it would be desirable to exit non successfully in this scenario.  In what situation would this be useful?

Comment: Related: [What does `while read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]` mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478720/what-does-while-read-r-line-n-line-mean)

Comment: This is one of a number of cases where a command will exit with a nonzero status because of something that isn't really an error (just maybe not a complete success) -- `grep` when it doesn't find a match, `cmp` and `diff` when the files don't match, even `(( someexpression ))` when the expression evaluates to 0 ("false" in arithmetic context).

Comment: @GordonDavisson: I consider all of those things to be failures.

Comment: @jesse_b That's just it, they're all debatable, depending on people's individual intuitions about what does and doesn't constitute a failure. Other people have certainly been [surprised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41078968/why-is-grep-c-with-0-count-exits-program-with-status-code-1) by [these](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276484/bash-set-o-errexit-problem-or-the-way-of-incrementing-variable). To me, the `read` behavior does make sense, because it failed to read a *complete* record (including terminator) from its input.

Comment: But these are all reasons why you should not use `set -e` routinely.

Comment: Why are you using `read` like this in the first place? You can embed newlines in a variable using a regular assignment.

Comment: You might just use `json=$(cat <<EOF\n...\nEOF\n)` where `\n` should be taken as an actual newline.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`read` reads a record (line by default, but ksh93/bash/zsh allow other delimiters with `-d`, even NUL with zsh/bash) and returns success as long as a full record has been read.

`read` returns non-zero when it finds EOF while the record delimiter has still not been encountered.

That allows you do do things like

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  ...
done < text-file
```

Or with zsh/bash

```
while IFS= read -rd '' nul_delimited_record; do
  ...
done < null-delimited-list
```

And that loop to exit after the last record has been read.

You can still check if there was more data after the last full record with `[ -n "$nul_delimited_record" ]`.

In your case, `read`'s input doesn't contain any record as it doesn't contain any NUL character. In `bash`, it's not possible to embed a NUL inside a here document. So `read` fails because it hasn't managed to read a full record. It stills stores what it has read until EOF (after IFS processing) in the `json` variable.

In any case, using `read` without setting `$IFS` rarely makes sense.

For more details, see [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123).

Answer (score 9):

This is one of the reasons I don't use `set -e` myself.

Now that you know that read will return 1 if it hits EOF without the given EOL delimeter, you can do one of:

```bsh
# depending on the contents of the input, it's an error
# if no data was read:
IFS= read -rd '' json <<EOF || [[ -n $json ]]
...
EOF

# or, you don't care at all how much data was read
IFS= read -rd '' json <<EOF || :
...
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

The command read is oriented to lines coming from user input by default, but to make it work in files it must be capable of detect when the data in the file is exhausted before reaching an end of line delimiter.

In the specific case of your example, the word EOF is used to delimit the inline text of the redirection operator *<<* and does not have any relation with the "end of file" indicator referred in read documentation, except in signaling tha interpreter that the data ends after the newline of the last line (with the closing curly brace). Of course, as the construct has complete data and does not come from a file, the situation where the end of file as an abrupt end of data condition cannot exist.

So the indication in the read's man page does not have actual application here, only if you were reading from a file or a data source which could mark the end as an eof (like the user pressing [Ctrl-D] or reaching the end of data in a pipe coming from another command).

This is compound with the special behaviour of the d and r options: -d causing to read everithing possible without regard to ends of lines, and (innecesary here, I suppose) -t causing read to ignore backslash escaped chars (that aren't present in the data and not needed as the text is inside quotes, except in the case where 'bar' should have some special character, like embedding binary data or unprintable chars), so this is clearly not intended for files as data sources.